# doubt about the calculation of the rest for a taylor's series

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to calculate some numbers with the help of series.
My problem is the calculation of the rest of the series.

For example I have to calculate $log 2$.

I can consider the function $$log (\frac{1+x}{1-x})$$ in which I can put $x= \frac{1}{3}$.

The series of Taylor for this function is:
$$log (\frac{1+x}{1-x}) = 2*\sum_{k=0}^ \infty \frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}$$
$$log (\frac{1+x}{1-x}) = 2*\sum_{k=0}^ n \frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}+ 2*\sum_{k=n+1}^ \infty \frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1} = 2*\sum_{k=0}^ n \frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}+ R_n$$

The passage that I can't understand it this:
$$R_n = 2*\sum_{k=n+1}^ \infty \frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1} < \frac{2 |x|^{2n+3}}{2n+3}\sum_{h=0}^ \infty x^{2k}$$ and then it becomes $\frac{2 |x|^{2n+3}}{2n+3} \frac{1}{1-x^2}$

NOTE
$$R_n = 2*\sum_{k=n+1}^ \infty \frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1} = 2*\sum_{h=0}^ \infty \frac{x^{2h+3}}{2h+3} =2 x^3 \sum_{h=0}^ \infty \frac{(x^2)^h}{2h+3}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $k \ge n+1$, $\vert x \vert^{2k+1} = \vert x \vert^{2n+3} x^{2(k-n-1)}$ and $\frac{1}{2k+1} \le \frac{1}{2n+3}$. Hence

$$2\sum_{k=n+1}^ \infty \frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1} \le \frac{2 |x|^{2n+3}}{2n+3}\sum_{h=0}^ \infty x^{2h}.$$

Finally $\sum_{h=0}^ \infty x^{2h}$ is the sum of the terms of a geometric sequence and therefore

$$\sum_{h=0}^ \infty x^{2k} = \frac{1}{1-x^2}$$ which provides the desired result.

Comment: I can't understand how I can change the variable h ... I wrote a note in the post

Comment: $h$ is a dummy variable. It can be replaced by whatever you want.

Comment: yes but how can you put the denominator of the term n out of the series so easily?